# Installing textbelt in nodejs VPS server

Tags: node.js, sms, digital-ocean

I have got a nodejs vps server at digitalocean and I am trying to install textbelt.

My steps :
cd /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/sendsms/public/sms
npm install

node server/app.js

install make as root

sudo apt-get install build-essential

wget http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz

tar xvzf redis-stable.tar.gz

cd redis-stable

make

sudo apt-get install mutt

Now I see this error
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /sms/ on this server.

Possible causes of this error include:

The request was forbidden by rules in the .htaccess file.
The directory you requested does not have an index.html or index.php file.
The permissions on the file or directory are incorrect.
For details about why the request was forbidden, see the Apache error log at:

/srv/users/SYSUSER/log/APPNAME/APPNAME_apache.error.log

PLEASE help me with this setup.

[image: Image screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

To run non-PHP apps such as Node.js apps with ServerPilot, [create a .htaccess file to proxy requests to the port your app is listening on](https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-run-apps-in-any-language.html).

To do this, you'll first need to find out which port your Node.js app is listening on. Then you can create the .htaccess file.

For example, if your Node.js app is listening on port 2345, your .htaccess file will look like this:

```
RewriteRule index.html http://localhost:2345/ [P]
RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost:2345/$1 [P]
```